# jquery mousedown event function cant pass handler

Tags: jquery, events, mouse

I've got this code:

```
function drawing(){
 this.dragging = function(){
 $('#object').mousedown(startDragging);
}

function startDragging(){
 console.log(e.PageX);
}
}

var draw = new drawing();
$('#object2').click(function(e){
draw.dragging();
})
```

and when Im traing to fire this up i got in console 'undefined' can anybody tell me where is my mistake?
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `event` object around if you want to reference it elsewhere (`e` doesn't exist until you define it somehow). This should work:

```
function drawing() {
    this.dragging = function(e) {
        $('#object').mousedown(startDragging(e));
    }

    function startDragging(event) {
        console.log(event.PageX);
    }
}

var draw = new drawing();

$('#object2').click(function(e) {
    draw.dragging(e);
})​
```

Comment: @Krystian: Oh, and `PageX` should be `pageX`, JS variables are case sensitive. That would do it...

Comment: ok you right my bad, but now I've got different problem - when I click object2 it's immediately fireing up the startDraging and I get coordinates from click event not from draging